# Looking for a way to turn verbs into present participle (ing form/gerund, english only)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for some library like the awesome [Humanizer](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) that would allow me to turn verbs like "get" into "getting", "read" into "reading", etc. Does something like that exist?

**Edit:** Looking at the comments and downvotes, some people don't realize this is not as trivial as it may appear, i.e. "learn" becomes "learning", but "run" becomes "ru**nn**ing".

Comment: Does not seem to be too hard problem. You can write a less-than-20-lines method to accomplish this easy task.

Comment: @Kilanny How? would you provide some help then?

Comment: I have provided already, but was not complete and got downvoted. `static string VerySimplePresent(string verb) {
  var voul = new[] { 'a', 'e', 'o', 'u', 'y' };
  var input = verb; //"get";
  if (voul.Contains(input[input.Length - 2]))
     return input + input[input.Length - 1] + "ing"; // getting
  return input + "ing"; // reading
}` you can complete over this

Comment: @Kilanny Nope, I am afraid it will need some kind of dictionary. Since there's alot of irregular verbs in english.

Comment: @choz atm I am implementing it via dictionary, however there are rules to build this present participle, but they are quite complex as you can see here http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/present-participle.html

Comment: @LuisFerrao How about an online dictionary + cURL ? Has it come to your mind?

Comment: You're only interested in a solution for English, or will other languages be involved in the future? And even if you say English-only, there are some differences between the various "dialects" of English.

Comment: @renniepet english only, I'm pretty sure "ing form" is an english only term